# Import Kotlin/Native framework in Cocoapod

Tags: ios, kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-native

I'm trying to add a vendored framework built with Kotlin/Native in a private CocoaPod but I get an error:

- I have generated an iOS framework with Kotlin/Native.
- I copy the framework folder (compiled/generated by Konan) into my custom pod folder
- In the podspec, I add the framework path in the "vendored_frameworks" list
- I launch `pod repo push myCocoapodsRepo myProject.podspec --verbose"`
- I receive an error :

`[iOS] xcodebuild:  fatal error: lipo: input file (/Users/jeandaube/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-auugdpsmbbpvarfzghxatkvwftsn/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/App.app/Frameworks/MyProject.framework/MyProject) must be a fat file when the -remove option is specified`

Should I somehow change the format of how I export the framework with Konan in a first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting the error because, by default, Kotlin Native only produces binaries for a single architecture.  CocoaPods than fails when it tries to treat it as a "fat" binary with multiple architectures.  Since you'll need multiple architectures anyway (at least arm64 for the device and x86_64 for the simulator) the approach I'm using is to create both architectures and then merge them with `lipo`  The resultant fat framework can then be vended by CocoaPods or just drag/drop installed in Xcode.

```
def outputDirectory = "$export_dir/$projectName/$projectVersion"
def outputFramework = "$outputDirectory/${projectName}.framework"

konanArtifacts {
    // Declare building into a framework, build arm64 for device, x64 for simulator                                                      
    framework(projectName, targets: ['ios_arm64', 'ios_x64' ]) {
        // The multiplatform support is disabled by default.                                   
        enableMultiplatform true
    }
}

// combine original arm64 and x64 libraries into a single library in
// the exported framework folder
task combineArchitectures(type: Exec, dependsOn: compileKonanLibrary) {
    executable 'lipo'
    args = [
            '-create',
            '-arch',
            'arm64',
            new File(compileKonanLibraryIos_arm64.artifact, 'Library'),
            '-arch',
            'x86_64',
            new File(compileKonanLibraryIos_x64.artifact, 'Library'),
            '-output',
            "$outputFramework/Library"
    ]
}

// export the arm64 (doesn't matter which really) framework, skipping
// the library binary itself
task exportFramework(type: Copy, dependsOn: compileKonanLibrary) {
    from compileKonanLibraryIos_arm64.artifact
    into outputFramework
    exclude projectName
    finalizedBy combineArchitectures
}

// build a pod spec by copying and updating a template file
task exportPodspec(type: Copy) {
    from "Library.podspec"
    into outputDirectory
    filter {
        it.replaceAll('@@projectName@@', projectName)
            .replaceAll('@@projectVersion@@', projectVersion)
    }
}

task export {
    dependsOn "exportFramework"
    dependsOn "exportPodspec"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin/Native does not produce multiarchitecture (aka fat) binaries (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) thus an attempt to run `lipo` on the framework it produces does not make sense.

Comment: Seems like it's possible to enable multiarchitecture in KN.

Comment: Not with current 1.3.30 EAP.